# how can i use setOpion() and getOption() method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am trying to first set in controller setOption(value, valuename) in controller and store in database and use it as getOption in views

but not working .

Here is my controller =>

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    mpc_m_c($request->server('SERVER_NAME'));
    $options = Config::all()->pluck('value','name');
    $tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);
    return view('admin.system-settings', compact('options', 'tzlist'));
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'app_name' => 'required',
        'currency_symbol' => 'required',
        'currency_code' => 'required',
        'date_format' => 'required',
        'home_page_description' => 'required',
        'recaptcha_private_key' => 'required',
        'minimum_deposit_amount' => 'required',
        'home_page_meta' => 'required',
        'notify_email' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {

        $file = $request->file('logo');
        $fileArray = array('logo' => $file);
        $rules = array(
            'logo' => 'mimes:png|required|' // max 10000kb
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($fileArray, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withErrors(['logo' => $errors['logo']]);

        } else {
            $logo = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('logo'));
            setOption('logo', $logo);
        }

    }

    if ($request->hasFile('banner')) {

        $file = $request->file('banner');
        $fileArray = array('banner' => $file);
        $rules = array(
            'banner' => 'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|required|' // max 10000kb
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($fileArray, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withErrors(['banner' => $errors['banner']]);

        } else {
            $banner = Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('banner'));
            setOption('banner', $banner);
        }

    }

    setOption('app_name', $request->input('app_name'));
    setOption('currency_symbol', $request->input('currency_symbol'));
    setOption('currency_code', $request->input('currency_code'));
    setOption('date_format', $request->input('date_format'));
    setOption('home_page_description', $request->input('home_page_description'));
    setOption('recaptcha_public_key', $request->input('recaptcha_public_key'));
    setOption('recaptcha_private_key', $request->input('recaptcha_private_key'));
    setOption('minimum_deposit_amount', $request->input('minimum_deposit_amount'));
    setOption('home_page_meta', $request->input('home_page_meta'));
    setOption('module_support_enabled', $request->input('module_support_enabled'));
    setOption('module_api_enabled', $request->input('module_api_enabled'));
    setOption('module_subscription_enabled', $request->input('module_subscription_enabled'));
    setOption('theme_color', $request->input('theme_color'));
    setOption('background_color', $request->input('background_color'));
    setOption('language', $request->input('language'));
    setOption('display_price_per', $request->input('display_price_per'));
    setOption('admin_layout', $request->input('admin_layout'));
    setOption('user_layout', $request->input('user_layout'));
    setOption('panel_theme', $request->input('panel_theme'));
    setOption('anonymizer', $request->input('anonymizer'));
    setOption('front_page', $request->input('front_page'));
    setOption('show_service_list_without_login', $request->input('show_service_list_without_login'));
    setOption('notify_email', $request->input('notify_email'));
    setOption('currency_separator', $request->input('currency_separator'));
    setOption('timezone', $request->input('timezone'));

    Session::flash('alert',  __('messages.updated_logout_needed'));
    Session::flash('alertClass', 'success');
    return redirect('/admin/system/settings');
}
```

route =>

```
  Route::get('/system/settings', 'ConfigController@edit');
        Route::put('/system/settings', 'ConfigController@update');
```

error =>

```
"Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\setOption()"
```

and view =>

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('home_page_meta') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="home_page_meta" class="control-label">meta tags</label>
                        <textarea
                                style="height: 150px;"
                                class="form-control"
                                data-validation="required"
                                rows="5"
                                id="home_page_meta"
                                name="home_page_meta"> <?php echo e($options['home_page_meta']) ?></textarea>

                    </div>
```

use =>

```
getOption('valuename')
```

And by this things he is using the function getOption(''valuename)  anywhere in the entire application ... i really dont want use it but just curious How he is using this things even there's no laravel build in funtion for this name?

*Note : Please don't judge me , I  just want to know ..thnaks

anybody got idea how do i use it ?

Comment: Is setOption part of a library or is it native to Laravel?

Comment: Could you give some context, what do you want to do? Laravel doesnt have a built in function setOption.

Comment: well i am quite new to laravel , i don't know how but i have seen a guy use this function in an application ,  i am adding full controller and views and route by editing my q.  please check again

Comment: There's no `setOption` built into Laravel nor PHP itself. You'd have to write one. It also doesn't really make sense to have one - you'd just do something like `$user->banner = 'foo';` to set the user's banner.